# UDP Packets Missing From RFID Receiver

Tags: networking, udp, wireshark, rfid, packets

I have an RFID receiver that constantly sends UDP packets to port 5757. When connected over ethernet to my desktop, all packets are received and valid (confirmed with Wireshark), and there is no issue. When I connect the receiver via ethernet to my laptop, not one UDP packet is received.

Things I have tried:
I have connected the laptop to the desktop over ethernet, and have sent UDP packets via netcat in both directions. Netcat has no issues with sending/receiving the data.

I've also captured and saved the RFID UDP packets on the desktop, and played them back using bittwist, first on the desktop, and had no issues capturing them in Wireshark(desktop). Then I copied the saved packets over to the laptop, played them back using bittwist, and had zero UDP packets captured in Wireshark(laptop).

Finally, I updated the ethernet driver and had the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UDP is a transport-layer protocol.  DNS is an application-layer protocol that traditionally runs on top of UDP.  That wireshark classifies your incoming packets as malformed DNS packets does not mean that they are not UDP.  It does not even mean that they are malformed -- it means that they are not correctly formed *DNS* messages, but that's to be expected.

Comment: If your data are not reaching a receiving program running on your laptop then your firewall is most likely responsible.

Comment: John, fair enough, but then why does wireshark choose to list them as malformed DNS packets instead of UDP packets? And the packets are reaching a receiving program, netcat listening on 5757.

EDIT: to clarify, the netcat-sent packets are being received on 5757, while the RFID packets are still missing.

Comment: If Wireshark, for whatever reason, sees the packets as DNS, then it does see them as UDP since DNS uses UDP. It is trying to go one step further to identify the specific protocol using UDP. By the way, TCP and UDP port 5757 is used for OpenMail X.500 Directory Server, and that may be confusing Wireshark in some way.

Comment: @aohcm, I have no way to determine why wireshark classifies the packets as malformed DNS packets (which, again, probably means that it *does* recognize them as UDP).  I speculate that their payloads in some way resemble DNS messages.  If on the laptop you are receiving the packets intact then your problem -- to the extent you have one at all -- is *wireshark*.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I connect the receiver via ethernet to my laptop"? Do you mean that you give the receiver your laptop's IP address the destination address for the UDP packets?

Comment: @RonMaupin answer about OpenMail is certainly the reason Wireshark classifies them as UDP. Probably you have different version of wireshark or different rules

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.
Both machines are running clean installs of Wireshark v1.12.7-0-g7fc8978 from master-1.12. I see now that the malformed packets is no longer the issue, and will update my question accordingly. Though there is still an issue; the RFID packets not arriving, while netcat packets do. @Ben that is correct. The receiver then sends UDP packets through a randomly selected port to port 5757.

Comment: I would be concerned about an application that uses a port number registered by IANA to a different application. Port 5757 is reserved by IANA for `OpenMail X.500 Directory Server`. See the IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry, page 95: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=95

Comment: Do you receive any packets from the RFID receiver? How is the RFID receiver assigned an _IP address_? Is it via _DHCP_? If so, does your laptop run a _DHCP_ server? If it's a static _IP address_, perhaps assigning a different one would help.